# Android Speech to text API Getting variable value out of onActivityResult method

Tags: java, android, text, methods, speech

Hi How can I use Android Speech to text API to get a value out of onActivityResult and use it in other activities/methods?

Heres the example code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if(requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

         String results1 = data.getStringExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
         EditText test = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         test.setText(results1);
    ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        whatYouSaid = results.get(0); }
```

So yeah.... How can i get this string value of whatYouSaid from this method to be able to use it in ohter methods/classes?

Comment: What is the value of `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS`? Have you tried replacing it with `data.getStringExtra("whatYouSaid")`? Are you able to post the code that is populating the `data` sent to `onActivityResult`?

Comment: Im not entirely sure. Ive got this example from http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Store it as a global static variable in your app.
2. Save this in Shared preferences.
3. If its just few more activities you can pass it through Intent;
4. SharedPreference:

starting from this line

```
.......
whatYouSaid = results.get(0);

 Sharedpreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("UR_UNIQ_PREF_ID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  Editor editor = sp.edit();
  editor.putString("WHATYOUSAID", whatyousaid);
 editor.commit();

//Then start your another activity

//Then in your next activity

oncreate(){

......
 Sharedpreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("UR_UNIQ_PREF_ID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String whatyousaid =  sp.getString("UR_UNIQ_PREF_ID","");

}
```

}

Comment: and how would i put that variable into shared preferences and then access it from a different activity?

Comment: how to store list of values ??